# Webpack reported size is huge compared to actual output

Tags: webpack

I'm getting that Webpack reported size is huge compared to actual output

```
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js" as it exceeds the max of "100KB".
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "node_modules/moment/moment.js" as it exceeds the max of "100KB".
Hash: 115ba034c25a5de14baa
Version: webpack 1.13.1
Time: 35574ms
      Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    dist.js     563 kB       0  [emitted]  main
dist.js.map     855 kB       0  [emitted]  main
 index.html  180 bytes          [emitted]  
   [0] multi main 28 bytes {0} [built]
    + 130 hidden modules
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
        + 4 hidden modules
```

the output is around 20kb, also it takes ages, around 10s

CONFIG:

```
/* globals __dirname, process */
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

var node_env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
console.log(node_env)

var config = {
  context: __dirname + '/client',
  entry: {
    main: [
      "./app.js"
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "./public",
    filename: "dist.js"
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'client'),
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/

      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loader: "style!css!less"
      },
      {
        test: /\.css/,
        loader: "style!css"
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    // you can now require('file') instead of require('file.js')
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.json']
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Webpack demo',
      hash: true,
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: __dirname + '/client/index.html',
    })
  ]
}

if (node_env === 'production') {
  config.plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    compress: {
      warnings: false
    }
  }));
}

module.exports = config
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume the question is about these lines:

```
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js" as it exceeds the max of "100KB".
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "node_modules/moment/moment.js" as it exceeds the max of "100KB".
```

That message is from `babel-loader` which encounters sources with gigantic sizes (over 100kb). Usually and in this exact case that means you (or some of your dependencies) require already bundled libraries (lodash and moment) which don't require processing through Babel.

The solution would be to excluded `node_modules/` from `babel-loader` configuration (add this to `module.loaders` section of your `webpack.config.js`):

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  exclude: /node_modules/
}
```

This works as the common expectation is to publish package on npm already compiled to es5 so they don't usually need to be processed through Babel.

Comment: If it solves your problem, could you accept the answer?

Comment: not yet, I still get the huge reported size and it takes ages to build. Does `exclude: /node_modules/` also exclude nested /node_modules folders?

Comment: @SuperUberDuper it should, could you share your webpack config?

Comment: sure, added to post

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my project:

assets/profile-view/dist/bundle.js" type="text/babel">

But after removing the {type="text/babel"} attribute from the code, the error message disappeared